# How can I iterate through a dictionary whose length changes in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I have a dictionary that I want to iterate through and change its value but I think the change of length might cause error, is there any good ways to do this?

example:

```
d = {'a':'orange','b':'pineapple','c':'dragonfruit'}
rating = {'orange':3, 'pineapple':4, 'dragonfruit':4.5, 'apple':3, 'pear': 3.5}

for key, value in d.items():
    if some conditions met:
        del d['a'] or d['e']='apple' # (or is not operator, i mean literally one of the operation add or delete item...)
```

for example:

```
for key, value in d.items():
    if rating[value]<4:
        del d[key]
```

or

```
d = {'a':['orange'],'b':['pineapple','peach'],'c':['dragonfruit']}
rating = {'orange':3, 'pineapple':4, 'dragonfruit':4.5, 'apple':3, 'pear': 3.5, 'peach': 5}
for key, value in d.items():
    rating_sum = sum([ rating[v] for v in value])
    if rating_sum > 8 and len(value)>1:
        d['e'] = d[key].pop(-1)
```

probably not the best example... means the dictionary's length changes in the loop.

Comment: I'm assuming the last line is pseudo-code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify list and dictionary during iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49646583/modify-list-and-dictionary-during-iteration)

Comment: **No**. Don't do this. Do a dict comprehension: `d2 = dict(k,v) for k in d if not cond(k)` as @jpp says.

Comment: @zvone: the other question is a bit different, it's more inquiring *"Why does deleting-items-while-iterating give error on a dict but not a list?"* whereas this question is *"How can I actually do this on a dict?"*

Comment: @smci If one question is *"why can't I do X"* and the other is *"how do I do X"*, then they are the same, because the answer to both is *"don't do X, do Y instead"*

Comment: @zvone neither of the 2 answers in the other question suggested "how to do Y" if you put it that way, they only explained "why X does not work'

Answer (score 5):

Don't add or remove keys while you iterate your dictionary. Also, do not shadow built-in `dict`.

You can use a dictionary comprehension with all your conditions:

```
d = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if \
     not (conditions and \
     ((k == 'a') or ((k, v) == ('e', 'apple'))))}
```

I presume your `conditions` are a function of `k` and `v`, otherwise you should calculate and apply this test outside of the dictionary comprehension.

But this can get a bit messy, so there's no harm in separating your logic into a function:

```
def keep_pair(k, v):
    if conditions:
        if (k == 'a') or ((k, v) == ('e', 'apple')):
            return False
    return True

d = {k, v for k, v in d.items() if keep_pair(k, v)}
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer, but is it doing the same thing as the `del dict['a'] or dict['e']='apple'` line? It looks like what you have will copy the original dict, applying conditions and always removing key 'a' and 'e',apple.

Comment: @TylerMarshall, I've updated my answer, which I *think* aligns with what OP wants. `del dict['e'] = 'apple'` in itself means nothing. You can't delete an assignment, what you can do is delete based on a key & value.

Comment: sorry i meant dict['e'] = 'apple' by adding an item

Comment: @raffa, Need more clarity, what's `conditions`, is it a function of `k` and `v`? If so, why would you set `d['e'] = 'apple'` *multiple times*? If possible, provide a **complete** [mcve] by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53656041/edit).

Comment: @jpp edited a bit, condition is function of v, more complicated in reality, i tried to put 2 simplified examples there. thanks

Comment: @raffa, Your second example makes no sense. If you have multiple values equal to `'pineapple'` do you set `d['e'] = 'pineapple`' multiple times? How is this assignment connected to your `for` loop?

Comment: @jpp edited again, the point of the second example was trying to show a situation where the length of dictionary has increased.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your dict to some temporary dict variable and then iterate through the temporary dict but making changes to the original.

```
temp = dict.copy()

for key, value in temp.items():
    if some conditions met:
        del dict['a'] or dict['e']='apple'
```

Comment: This is fine for small dictionaries, memory inefficient for larger ones. Except for use of `dict` as a variable name, which you should *never* do.

Answer (score 0):

Don't. It's not impossible but in most cases there's no reason to not build a new dictionary and reassign the name, which is easier to write and read.

```
d = <SOME-DICT>
# filter d with dict comprehension, reassign the name d
d = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if <FILTERING-CONDITION>}
```

Some demos::

```
>>> d = {'a':'orange','b':'pineapple','c':'dragonfruit'}
>>> {k:v for k,v in d.items() if v != 'pineapple'}
{'a': 'orange', 'c': 'dragonfruit'}
>>> {k:v for k,v in d.items() if not (k == 'd' and v == 'dragonfruit')}
{'a': 'orange', 'b': 'pineapple', 'c': 'dragonfruit'}
>>> {k:v for k,v in d.items() if not (k == 'c' and v == 'dragonfruit')}
{'a': 'orange', 'b': 'pineapple'}
>>> {k:v for k,v in d.items() if not (k == 'a' or (k == 'e' and v == 'pineapple'))}
{'b': 'pineapple', 'c': 'dragonfruit'}
```